# can I call current context from fcm's myBackgroundMessageHandler in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to call `context` of the current class from m`yBackgroundMessageHandler` in flutter or is it an impossible task?

```
Future<dynamic> _myBackgroundMessageHandler
    (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
//how do I access context from here?
Navigator.pop(context);
  return PushNotificationService().showNotification(message);
}
class PushNotificationService{
  static BuildContext _context;

  static init({@required BuildContext context}) {
    _context = context;
  }
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  Future initialize(context) async{
    print("initialised!");
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    var initializationSettings =
    InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: selectNotification);
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        fetchRideInfo(message['data']['orderId'], context, "onMessage");
      },
    onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null:_myBackgroundMessageHandler,

      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        fetchRideInfo(message['data']['orderId'], context, "onResume");
      },
    );
    ///fetch user messaging token here
    getToken();
  }
  void fetchRideInfoInBackground() {
    print("incoming Request");
    assetsAudioPlayer.open(
      Audio('sounds/alert.mp3'),
    );
    assetsAudioPlayer.play();
  }
  Future<String> getToken() async{
    print("fetching token");
    token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    print('token got as: $token');
    return token;

  }

  void fetchRideInfo(orderId, context, String type) {
    print("fetching info");
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
          CustomProgressDialog(status:'Fetching details',),);
    if(type!="onResume"){
      assetsAudioPlayer.open(
        Audio('sounds/alert.mp3'),
      );
      assetsAudioPlayer.play();
      print(orderId);
    }

    orderIdString = orderId;

      Provider.of<MainBloc>(context, listen: false).
      fetchRideInfo(context, orderId).then((value){
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
              RideRequestPage(orderId: orderId)),
        );
      }).catchError((error) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        AlertManager.showToast(error.toString());
      });

  }

  Future showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel id',
      'channel name',
      'channel desc',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      playSound: true,
      icon: "ic_stat_ic_notification",
      largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap("ic_launcher"),
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("alert")
    );

    var platformChannelSpecifics =
    new NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'New Incoming Request',
      'New incoming ride request',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'Default_Sound',
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: how do you use `_myBackgroundMessageHandler`?

Comment: please review my updated code